# Where can I watch Carlsen - Karjakin with video + commentaries?

Tags: world-championship

Does anyone have tips on where to watch the (now ongoing) World Championship match between Carlsen and Karjakin? I'm looking for live commentaries and a video feed if that's available. Thanks!

Comment: You could follow the Champions showdown in St Louis on Chess Studio - a YouTube channel. That tournament is producing more interesting games.

Answer (score 9):

There's live commentary from two GMs on Chess24's youtube channel:
https://www.youtube.com/user/chess24media

They have video, but only of the commentators (not the players), together with an analysis board

Answer (score 5):

You can get live moves and commentary from various websites such as chess24  or Spiegel.de or...

If you want the video of the players you have to register and pay at the worldchess website.

Also, in Norway (and perhaps Russia) the match is broadcast on TV

Comment: If one pays for the official video feed, can the games be viewed later, or can they only be viewed "live" while the game is in progress?  Not knowing this is the only thing that's stopped me from signing up for it, since I can not usually watch during the scheduled times.

Comment: FYI, I answered by own comment/question above, by paying the $15 to buy the video streaming...  The answer is, yes, you can go back and watch the video of prior rounds, after they're played...

Answer (score 4):

There are several places you can watch live commentaries, and only one place you can watch the video feed of the players. Some of these are:

- [The official Agon/World Chess website](https://worldchess.com/nyc2016/) has both live video feed and commentary, for prices from $15 and up – however, the feed can be watched for free at http://wcc.protectedvideos.com if you use Android (or if you spoof your user agent), but I don't know if that's legal
- [Chess24](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/carlsen-karjakin-world-chess-championship-2016) has live video commentary and analysis
- [ChessBomb](https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2016-carlsen-karjakin-world-chess-championship) has live web analysis and commentary
- [analysis.sesse.net](http://analysis.sesse.net/) has no commentary, but a deep multi-PV analysis of ongoing games
- [The Norwegian public broadcaster NRK](http://nrk.no/sjakk/) (on web and the TV channel NRK2) has live video and Norwegian commentary, it's geolocked, [but you can get around that](https://www.reddit.com/r/norsk/comments/2dshka/tutorial_how_to_watch_nrktv_while_being_outisde/) – again, no idea if that's legal
- Ditto the Norwegian web TV channel [VGTV](http://www.vgtv.no/#!/kategori/100157/sjakk-vm-2016)

Some background information for the coverage of this year's world championship: Agon, the official partner of FIDE for the world chess championship cycle, owns the international rights to the official video feed(s) of the players through World Chess. Nobody else is permitted to broadcast it internationally.

(The feed is produced by NRK, the Norwegian public broadcaster, who retains the right to broadcast it on their national TV channels, and the Norwegian web TV channel VGTV has also purchased the rights to broadcast it from NRK. If you live in Norway (or can pretend you do), you can watch it for free, with Norwegian commentary.)

Agon *also* tried to retain the sole rights to relay the actual moves made in the games. They sued Chess24 because they planned to relay the moves with commentary anyway, and [Agon lost the case](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/chess24-win-moscow-case-announce-new-york-line-up). They are currently contemplating whether to appeal.